# open mp threads and a loop

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, openmp

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(newgrid,grid,maxdiff,epsilon) private(i,j,diff,maxdiff1,grid0,num_iter)
{   
    do{
    #pragma omp critical
    maxdiff = 0;
    //num_iter=num_iter+1;
    #pragma omp for
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    {   
        maxdiff1 = 0;
        for (j=1;j<n;j++){
            grid0 = grid[i+(n+1)*j];
            newgrid[i+(n+1)*j] = (grid[i-1+(n+1)*j]+grid[i+1+(n+1)*j]+grid[i+(n+1)*(j-1)]+grid[i+(n+1)*(j+1)]-h*h*f[i-1+(n-1)*(j-1)])/4;
            diff = fabs(newgrid[i+(n+1)*j]-grid0);
            grid[i+(n+1)*j] = newgrid[i+(n+1)*j];
            if (diff>maxdiff1) 
                maxdiff1 = diff;
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        if (maxdiff1 > maxdiff) maxdiff = maxdiff1; 
    }
    }while(maxdiff>=epsilon);
}
```

insead of initializing openmp every do{}while() loop I create the theads before the loop and parallelize the i loop amongst threads. the problem is it doesn't work correctly on 2 threads though correctly on 1, and it stuck from time to time.

Comment: There's no value in placing all of your code in one big omp scope. It just makes the code harder to understand and doesn't affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition when you write to `newgrid`.  For example when `i` of one thread is the same as `i-1` of another thread (same goes for `j`).  Use a critical section when you write to newgrid if you want to get the correct result.

```
    do {
        maxdiff = 0;
        #pragma omp for private(i,j, diff, maxdiff1, grid0)
        for (i=1;i<n;i++) {   
            maxdiff1 = 0;
            for (j=1;j<n;j++) {
                grid0 = grid[i+(n+1)*j];
                #pragma omp critical
                newgrid[i+(n+1)*j] = (grid[i-1+(n+1)*j]+grid[i+1+(n+1)*j]+grid[i+(n+1)*(j-1)]+grid[i+(n+1)*(j+1)]-h*h*f[i-1+(n-1)*(j-1)])/4;
                diff = fabs(newgrid[i+(n+1)*j]-grid0);
                grid[i+(n+1)*j] = newgrid[i+(n+1)*j];
                if (diff>maxdiff1) 
                    maxdiff1 = diff;
            }
            #pragma omp critical
            if (maxdiff1 > maxdiff) maxdiff = maxdiff1; 
        }
    }while(maxdiff>=epsilon);
```